# KDC Encrption and Decryption

Tags: kerberos

Hacker is able to sniff the traffic between the editor, the KDC and the network scanner during the key exchange. Is he/she able to decrypt the sniffed data key?

Comment: Please share any code that you have written, solutions you have tried, or sources you have read within your question. By doing this it'll help give us greater context to help you.

Comment: it is not code based question. It is from Kerberos topic. What will happen if someone have key. Is he she able to change your data or can have direct connection with server,

Answer (score 0):

According to RFC 4120, the long term keys are never sent in the messages, either clear or encrypted. Short term keys are always encrypted with a long term key or another short term key.